# total distance and driving time in optaplanner (vehicle routing)

Tags: optaplanner, vehicle-routing

I am trying to solve VRP with OptaPlanner, after getting the best solution is there a way to get total distance and driving time for each vehicle of the solution? Also, how can I get vehicle arrival time and service completion time for specific customer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `RoadLocation`, split up the `travelDistanceMap` into a map for driving time and a map for road distance. Look for the code that creates that `travelDistanceMap` (for example from graphhopper in my vrp-dataset-generator repo) and instantiate both there.